# In C#, is there a way to define a type synonym?

Tags: c#, types, type-alias, type-synonyms

In my C# project, I have a need for a long union type of the form:

```
System.Tuple<..., ..., ...>
```

where the `...`'s are components with names long enough that the whole tuple type declaration stretches for an entire line's width.

Does C# support a way to shorthand this?

I'm imagining something like Haskell's [type synonyms](https://wiki.haskell.org/Type_synonym), where I can declare a short type name to use in place of the long one as easily as I can declare a new variable.

I tried using `var`, but since I need to to declare the type of a parameter to `delegate`, I get an error reading "the contextual keyword 'var' may only appear within a local variable declaration or in script mode"; it appears that simply using `var` will not work for my case.

Comment: The hallmark of good language design is not what to put in but what to intentionally leave out.  C# is a well-designed language.  You've driven that Tuple quite beyond what's reasonable, that many type parameters is only suitable for auto-generated code.  Declare a class or struct so you have good property/field names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is:

```
using MyAlias = MyLongType
```

It is called **using alias directive**. It also works for **Namespaces**. More information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive).

However this works only inside only 1 file. 
You either need to write it in every file you will use it, or use the workaround:

Inherit from the class with the long type, and don't add anything to the functionality.

**Example:**

```
class  MyAlias: MyLongType{}
```

Answer (score 2):

Straight from the documentation

[using directive (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive)

> To create an alias for a namespace or a type. This is called a using
>   alias directive.
>
> `using Project = PC.MyCompany.Project;`

Eg

```
using ShortTypeName = My.Very.Silly.Long.TypeName.That.is.VerySuspiciousAndProbablyShouldBeRefactoredAnyway;`
using ShortOtherTypeName = My.Very.Silly.Long.TypeName.That.is.VeryOtherSuspiciousAndProbablyShouldBeRefactoredAnyway;`

internal class Program
{
    private (ShortTypeName , ShortOtherTypeName ) _myLovelyTuple;
```

Comment: Why declare both types when you could declare the Tuple directly? If the types themselves are short this is useless

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto indeed you could :)